# 404 Error When Verifying Email in Dj-Rest-Auth

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-auth, dj-rest-auth

I'm developing an authentication API for a mobile app using dj-rest-auth in Django. After a user registers an account, a verification email is sent to the user with an activation key. However, when I try to verify the email by sending a POST request to the verification endpoint, I receive a 404 Not Found error. I'm unsure where the issue lies.

```
# main project urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    # Other URL patterns...
    path('register/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    # ...
]
```

Settings

```
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True

#ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = ''
#ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = ''

SITE_ID = 1

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myEmail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 7
#EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER")
#EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PASSWORD")




REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ]
}
SIMPLE_JWT  = {
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'email',
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=10),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
}
LOGIN_URL = 'https://localhost:8000/login/'

REST_AUTH = {
        'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER' : 'users.serializers.CustomUserDetailsSerializer',
        'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.UserRegisterSerializer',
        'USE_JWT': True,
        'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'my-app-auth',
        'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE': 'my-refresh-token',
        'JWT_AUTH_HTTPONLY':False,
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

## Issue:

When I try to verify the email by sending a POST request to the `/register/verify-email/` endpoint with the activation key, I'm receiving a 404 Not Found error with body
`{ "detail": "Not found." }`

I'd appreciate any guidance on what might be causing the 404 error during the email verification process. If you've encountered a similar issue or if you have suggestions on how to troubleshoot this, I'd be grateful for your insights.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `dj_rest_auth.registration.urls`?

Comment: it can be found here. 
[dj_rest_auth.registration.urls](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/blob/master/dj_rest_auth/registration/urls.py)

Comment: Try setting `DEBUG = True` in settings.py.  This should give you an informative error page for the 404 error, explaining exactly what urls it tried and why it didn't match.

Comment: Actually, The endpoint exists, and the response is {"detail": "Not found.} Status Code 404 I think the problem mabey with the token

Answer (score 0):

404 Not found error means that the url you're looking for doesn't exist:

you're looking for /register/verify-email/,
make sure it exists in your dj_rest_auth.registration.urls

Comment: Actually, The endpoint exists and the response is 
`{"detail": "Not found.} Status Code 404`

I think the problem mabey with the token

Comment: You can also check this blog post, https://testdriven.io/blog/django-rest-auth/